# Unable to find Index of an element in the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 select elements with the class 'status' like this:

```
<select class = "status">
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
<select class = "status">
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
<select class = "status">
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
```

If I have to add an event listener for all of them how do I know which one is changed?

It works when I write the jquery code like this:

```js
$(".status").change(function(){console.log("changed")})
```

But I'm unable to find the index of the select tag which has changed in the class. Please help..

Comment: Why do you need the index? You can refer directly to the element using `this`, ie `$('.status').on('change', function() { console.log(this) })`

Comment: It worked, I was trying 'this' parameter and it kept giving me an error, I thought may be there's a DOM method to do it the right way.  Thank you very much, Phil!

Answer (score 1):

The code would apply to whatever `.status` element changed. In JS, `this` always references the current element that triggered the event. Since in this case that would be a single item, there wouldn't be an index per se. But in JQuery, you would use `index()`. I'd suggest writing it like this so you can use event delegation if needed.

```js
$(".status").on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this));
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class = "status">
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
<select class = "status">
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
<select class = "status">
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) with `$(this)`.

```js
$(".status").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).index())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="status">
  <option value='completed'>Completed></option>
  <option value='Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
<select class="status">
  <option value='completed'>Completed></option>
  <option value='Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
<select class="status">
  <option value='completed'>Completed></option>
  <option value='Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'd use `$(this).index('.status')` to limit the range to only the elements in question

Comment: There are so many way to catch index. Thanks for alternative.

Answer (score -1):

its better add other class beside

```
<select class = "status class1">
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
<select class = "status class2" >
    <option value ='completed'>Completed></option>
    <option value = 'Inprogress'>In progress</option>
</select>
```

$(".status").change(function(){  if($(this).is(".class1") )  })